# String too long XML parsing with SAX (Java)

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am parsing a big xml file (around 50mb) with SAX parser and i'm encountering a problem which i cannot solve with the answer I found on the forum :

[parsing huge length string using sax parser in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108350/parsing-huge-length-string-using-sax-parser-in-android)

My problem is in the "Characters" function.

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException { 

        if(mQuery){
             String vQuery = new String(ch,start,length);
              ...
              }
```

The queries I am parsing can sometimes be really huge (>2500 characters) and I heard that the maximum chunk size that SAX can parse is 1024. This is why my program is hanging when it encounters a huge string.

I tried the workaround given in the previous post (appending the String with a temporary string or using a StringBuilder object) and none of those worked.

I'm not willing to use another xml parser because of performance issues: it's a small program and it's meant to execute fast.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: i think you have to take apart your xml file !! @Stefan

Comment: Which means what more precisely ?

Comment: The "workaround" of using a StringBuilder is not actually a workaround.  It's the normal way the `characters` method should be coded.  Please post a complete `characters` method that is using this approach and failing.  And describe the failure a bit more.